# Question about the hands with one heart and one seven excluding the $7$ of hearts

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

The answer is $\binom{12}1 \binom31 \binom{36}3$ which makes sense. Number $\binom{12}1 \binom31$ accounts for the first two cards. I was wondering why counting the combinations of the other three cards as $\binom{12}3 \binom31 \binom31 \binom31$ doesn't work. We choose three cards out of eleven denominations (can't choose $7$), then choose suits for each card out of available three because hearts are not allowed.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I think your calculation does not agree with what you wrote about your calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term $\binom{12}{3}$ is the number of selections without repetition. Thus it only counts combinations with different denominations, not for example 6-6-6.

Even if this was fixed, you would have to take into account that there is only one of each suit when counting the suits.

Comment: @ pettni, so $\binom{12}1 \binom {11}1 \binom {10}1$ instead of $\binom {12}3$ should fix half the problem, right? Is it possible to account for repeating suits using the method in my OP?

Comment: The number of ways to select 3 denominations with repetition is $\binom{12+3-1}{3}$, I can't think of a simple way to count the number of ways to select suits, since $\binom{12+3-1}{3}$ contains inhomogeneous selections like $6-6-6$ (just 1 way) as well as $3-4-5$ (9 ways).

Comment: Thanks. One last question. $\binom {12}3$ is the number of selections without repetition, $\binom{12 + 3 - 1}3$ is the number of selections with repetitions. How is $\binom{12}1 \binom{11}1 \binom{10}1$ different from the above two?

Comment: The number $\binom{12}{3}$ represents the number of ways to select 3 out of 12 objects without repetition. With $\binom{12}{1}\binom{11}{1}\binom{10}{1}$ you also select three different objects but *with ordering*. Therefore e.g. 1-2-3 and 2-3-1 will be considered different selections in the latter but the same in $\binom{12}{3}$. With the definition of the binomial term you can show that $\binom{12}{3} = \binom{12}{1}\binom{11}{1}\binom{10}{1} / 6$, the $6$ here accounts for the number of possible ways to arrange 3 items in different orders.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm guessing you want to draw a five-card hand so that you have exactly one heart and exactly one seven but not the seven of hearts.

As you say, there are $12$ hearts allowed, so the $12\choose 1$ makes sense. Then there are $3$ sevens allowed so the $3\choose 1$ makes sense.

Now you need three more cards. There were $52$ cards in the deck, but you cannot pick a heart ($13$ of them) or a seven ($3$ of them not double-counting the heart). This gives a factor of $36\choose 3$.

You're question is why we cant write ${12\choose 3}{3\choose 1}{3\choose 1}{3\choose 1}$ to represent picking three denominations, then picking a suit three times. The issue is that you can pick the same denomination more than once. As @pettni noted, you could draw, for example, three sixes. You can verify that ${36\choose 3}\neq {12\choose 1}{3\choose 1}{3\choose 1}{3\choose 1}$.

Comment: OP used $\binom{12}{\color{red}{3}}\binom{3}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{3}{1}$ and avoids repeating the specific rank-suit card multiple times.  (*the six of spades can only occur once*).  The error was that OP's method only counts the scenarios where the three non-7-non-heart cards are all different ranks while avoiding any of the possibilities where a rank is repeated.  (*e.g. where $6\spadesuit,~6\diamondsuit,~3\spadesuit$ are the extra three cards*)

Comment: Thanks; I misread this. I'll reconsider.